# Nginx hosting with path appended to index.php

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I'm hosting an instance on Concrete5, and in addition to using a dynamic paths, they also use URLs in the weird form of `www.mysite.com/index.php/path/to/page`.

I have it mostly working, but I'm having issues getting Nginx to serve requests to `www.mysite.com/`, as it's listing the directory instead of displaying `index.php`.

- www.mysite.com/ -> lists the `public` directory, but should display index.php
- www.mysite.com/index.php/path/to/page -> works!
- www.mysite.com/some/other/path -> works!

Here's my Nginx conf file:

```
server {

    root /srv/www/mysite.com/public_html;
    server_name mysite.com

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php/$request_uri;
        autoindex on; # just for debugging...
    }

    location ~ \.php($|/) {
        set $script $uri;
        if ($uri ~ "^(.+\.php)(/.+)") {
            set $script $1;
        }
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$script;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration is missing `index index.php;`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was missing. Thanks/derp!